# pandas: plot mean values within bins - formatting help needed

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bins

I am doing some solar system dynamics simulations, and have been using this project as an excuse to teach myself some python/pandas. The resulting data set has a little over 1000 records, with values for orbital inclination, eccentricity and so on for each of the bodies involved.

I'm trying to use pandas to study the mean orbital inclinations of the ~1000 bodies ('test particles') in the result data, as a function of semi-major axis.

So far, what I've been doing is this:

1) read the data into a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('final.csv')
```

2) limit the data to a range of semi-major axis values (the particles 'spread out' over the course of the simulations, but I want to limit my analysis

```
cf = df[df.a.between(30,80)]
```

3) plot the mean value for inclination for a given number of bins

```
cf.groupby(pd.cut(cf.a, 80))['inc'].mean().plot()
```

This creates an acceptable plot, but formatting-wise it has a couple of problems: unless it's completely maximized to fill my screen, the numbers along the x axis get squished together and overlap. They are also not exactly what I'd like to see: they show the max and min for bins, where I would prefer a straight ticking by 5s or something similar.

[pandas output from above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Ww6.png)

I've tried passing values `(x=None, xticks=None)` in to the `plot()` part of the string above, but this has had no effect on the resulting plot. Is plot/output control possible with the way I'm doing this?

Thanks,

G

Comment: See dupe on how to rotate xticks.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This is not about rotating ticks. It is about getting straight normal ticklabels for a plot which has been grouped by bins. To avoid confusion, could you, Gleen, make this point clearer in the question?! Also it would help to provide a [mcve] of the issue (see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Trusting you, reopened the dupe. If you find a better suited dupe, please re-close.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm not even sure if the asked is possible. But I guess one should not prevent this from being answered in case someone has a good idea about it. The [mcve] would allow to seek for alternatives (maybe not using `cut` and binning data differently would help).

Comment: Thanks all. I will work on the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. In the meantime the solution offered by KPLauritzen seems to work well. I look forward to learning more about all of this -- it's fun!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I want to do something like this, I go to matplotlib directly. 
I will show a small example with this sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 7], [3, 6], [4,7], [5,3]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Instead of cutting it with `pd.cut`, I make cuts with `np.linspace`. 
So

```
bins = np.linspace(0,5,4)
group = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.A, bins))
```

Now, to plot it, I want the middle of the bins

```
plot_centers = (bins [:-1] + bins [1:])/2
plot_values = group.B.mean()
```

and plot with

```
plt.plot(plot_centers, plot_values)
```

You should be careful handling missing data, ie if you have a bin with no data in it. In that case you can use `fillna(0)`, to make all `NaNs` 0.

```
plot_values = group.B.mean().fillna(0)
```